# Two Dimensional Array Nested for of Column Row instead of Row Column

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I'm preparing a program based on a multiple choice test.

```
int[][] answers = {
    {3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4},
    {0, 0, 2, 1, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1},
    {3, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 2, 5, 0, 3},
    {3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 0, 3, 1}
};

int[] correctA = {3, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1};
```

There are 4 students.
I want to know which question is chosen wrong, correct or left empty how many times.
I found out which student chose wrong, correct or left empty how many times with a nested for (by going like **first row, first column,** **first row second column**), but now I can't do it this way (Now I want to be like **first row first column, second row first column**).

Example:

First question:

3 students chose correct,
1 student chose wrong

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question. Could you please clarify what you are asking?

Comment: What I'm asking is , instead of the program taking first row first column, then first row second column, I want it to take the first row first colund, second row first column. Like we have {{1,2},{3,4}}, With a nested for I can only look firstly to 1, then 2, then 3, then 4. But instead I want it to look to it as 1,3,2,4.  That way I can understand how many students chose wrong,true or left empty at first question, then second question so on and so forth

Comment: Use [edit] option to clarify your question (like with example of actual expected result). Don't do it via comments, since (a) not everyone is reading them so if question is still unclear you are limiting amount of people willing to help you (b) it is not their purpose, we have them to *ask* for clarifications, not as *chat* replacement. Also showing honest attempts to solve the problem makes people more willing to help so consider including your (even failed) code/pseudocode and describe problem which you are facing/which is stopping you from moving forward.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/, aka http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/, at least as far as we can see in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner loop will iterate the students.

Your outer loop variable should be an integer index which goes from 0 up to the total number of questions (preferably this should be defined as a constant somewhere but we will use `correctA.length`).

```
    for(int question=0; question < correctA.length; question++) {
        int correct = correctA[question];
        for (int[] student : answers) {
            int answer = student[question];
            // Check answer==correct ?
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, what should I do after this , sorry I'm new to Java.

Comment: Please **[post a new question if you have a new question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions)** Do not use followup comments to ask new questions if the original question was already solved.